# lynx error after install says "HTTP/1.0 302 moved" and I don't know why

Tags: centos, lynx

I have tried to install lynx on my server running Centos 6.2 several times. I have tried by rpm, and also from scratch with ./configure , make, make install, as well as during post install in a ks script. No matter how I do it I run into the same issue, it says it's installed but when I run "lynx www.yahoo.com" it just says "HTTP/1.0 302 moved" and hangs. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing especially wrong in that error message. It means that Yahoo is redirecting your browser from www.yahoo.com to something else. Normal website behavior.

Try waiting a little longer and pressing the space bar if nothing changes. Lynx has to download and present the new page after it gets the 302 message.

Comment: it does that regardless of the url though, and not on another server running the same os on the same network so something has to be wrong somewhere. There is a SSL VPN that needs to be authenticated, so I tried using: lynx google.com -pauth uname:pwd -accept_all_cookies   but still get the error. now, if I use https:/google.com it will bring me to google (even without authenticating, oddly) but if I try to leave or search it gives me the error again. Waiting does nothing, nor does the spacebar.

Comment: The VPN business is a little outside my experience. Try curl -vIL with your URL and authentication. That should help obtain a clearer picture of the redirection you're seeing.